# How to retain special characters in file names when converting from SVN to Mercurial (Windows)?

Tags: version-control, encoding, mercurial

I'm using `hg convert` to convert a SVN repository to Mercurial. But special characters like æ, ø and å (Danish) comes out as Ã¦ Ã¸ and Ã¥ in file names.

The exact command I used was:

```
hg convert http://svn.server/path/to/repo repo-hg
```

I'm using TortoiseHg 2.1.4 with Mercurial 1.9.3 on Windows 7.

How can I retain the original special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those messed up characters are UTF-8 mistranslated as (likely) Windows-1252.  As @LazyBadger said, the global option `--encoding utf8` may be able to help.  Can you point me to a public Danish server to try to clone?

Comment: I prepared filename with vowels in filename and content here http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/ for you. Good luck

Comment: @LazyBadger: I could display the files correctly by executing `set HGENCODING=utf8` in console, then launching `thg`.  The GUI would then display file, comment and content correctly for the Danish file,  but adding new files broke.  Seems they still are encoded and stored as cp1252.  Next I used "hg manifest" to find all the "special" files and create a filemap to be used for an hg-to-hg conversion (`hg convert --filemap <filemap> <hg-old> <hg-new>`).  I gave the correct name for the file and ended up with a usable database.

Comment: Mark, mercurial doesn't convert any data in charset-dependent manner, thus - if you want to add Danish filename, you have (?) to have Danish-compatible environment before (my locale isn't 1252, but I could add file) HGENCODING affects only Mercurial, your system (console or GUI) uses another charset. And, BTW, split your comment and add it into answer for Jacob (which I can upvote). I'm not interested anymore in topic and problem after downvoting my **correct** answer by stupid moron

Comment: Creating a filemap was the solution that worked for me. Thanks Mark.

Answer (score 0):

You miss global option `--encoding ENCODING`, where encoding must be charset of your filename (i.e after some chcp XXX you can read filename in `svn ls`, you'll be able read filename correctly after polished convert)